# Mac prompts with `Enter passphrase for key on every login

Tags: ssh, osx

I regularly use my Mac to `ssh` into other systems on my local network.

I have a public/private key (which was created 6 years ago) so I can connect without using a password.

Recently (probably since upgrading to 10.12.4) the Mac prompts with Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':

Why has this suddenly started happening?
(I presume this has something to do with changes to `ssh` `OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0`)

Can I get `ssh` to connect without asking for passphrase?

Alternatively I can use a new key pair, but can I `ssh-keygen` to remove the passphrase without affecting the public key?

There seem to be a number of related questions, but no solutions which seem applicable to the Mac.

Possibly useful information:-

`id_rsa`

```
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,0F1575DBFB9CA6CD
```

`ssh-add -l` shows

```
2048 SHA256:XQGzZVv9orlvUu6t7XIfxi89EaroG9CU2Z2WQ71kST8 ~/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

`ssh-agent`

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/b7/k8m8pvdx0kl3kjhbk8q2kchm0000gn/T//ssh-gmetYqUf36ZC/agent.10219; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=10220; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 10220;
```

Comment: I would say that could be solved using keychan, it you do not mind compromising your security.  I would regenerate that key with a more modern crypto too.

Answer (score 6):

If you generated the key pair with a passphrase, this is the desired behaviour. If you don't want to enter a passphrase, chose an empty one.

If it would be possible to generate a new key with the same public key, there wouldn't be any security anymore, so you can't do that.

I suggest to let Keychain enter the password for you. Edit `~/.ssh/config` and add the option:

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: Maybe "this is the desired behaviour", but **NOT** the way it has been working for the last 4 years. I tried both options; create a new key without passphrase. This works but now prompts for password. I might as well just allow `ssh` password access. The `UseKeychain` seemed to make to difference.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood me: Not the behaviour you desired, just from ssh point of view ("if you don't want to enter a passphrase, don't give one on generating). So, did the option solve your problem?

Comment: `UseKeychain` did not work. I have read the `ssh_config` man, but the passphrase never seemed to be added or accessed. The new key without passphrase works, when I set the `-i` on `ssh`